# Chrome.notifications.create doesn't work, throws no lastError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am unable to get chrome extension notification to work.

I believe it has all required pieces and lastError throws no errors in console (undefined). The icon file is present as well. I also added web_accessible_resources in the manifest but it doesn't seem to matter in this case.

Part of manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon.png"
],

"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "notifications"
]
```

Part of options.js:

```
function resetTotal() {
chrome.storage.sync.set({'total':0}, function(){
    var opt = {
        type: "basic",
        title: "Total reset",
        message: "Total has been reset back to 0.",
        iconUrl: "icon.png"
    }
    chrome.notifications.create('reset', opt, function(){console.log("last error: ", chrome.runtime.lastError)});
});

resetButton.addEventListener("click", resetTotal, false);
```

Comment: No need for web_accessible_resources. So far it sounds like https://crbug.com/825497

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have Google Chrome notifications enabled in Windows. Go to configurations > notifications & actions and enable notifications. If it still does not show up, try changing the ID of the notification. It might be that it displayed once but not anymore because you have not clicked it. Try clicking it in the notification center located on the bottom right of your screen.

Comment: Without ID work as much you need `
                chrome.notifications.create(notifOptions);`